# Rolling Average in Power Query

Tags: powerbi

I am a complete newbie to Power BI

I am trying to reproduce this type of calculation in the Power Query Editor of Power BI.

The screenshot is from Excel and in column C it uses AVERAGE($B$2: B2) and the next row is AVERAGE($B$2: B3) and so on.

C2 = ((168 + 313) / 2) = 241

C3 = (((168 + 313) + 301) / 3) = 261

and so on

Is there a way to do this type of calculation in Power Query?

[image]

Comment: This can be done in the query editor as well, but is there a reason it needs to be done there?

Comment: Alex, There are a lot more columns that I left out for question clarity. In the end, the data is unpivoted and the column names become row names them displayed in a matrix visual.

Comment: That's fine. DAX and M both work better on unpivoted data than pivoted data. Are you saying you need to pivot after calculating the average?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Power Query M language, you can do a similar thing. Filter the rows up to and including the current row's date and then average the `CallsPresent` column.

```
= List.Average(
      Table.SelectRows(
          #"[Previous Step Name Here]",
          (C) => C[FullDate] <= [FullDate]
      )[CallsPresent]
  )
```

---

The `#"[Previous Step Name Here]"` bit is simply the table that you are doing the selection on. A query in the query editor is generally a list of steps where you do one transformation at a time. So your new step is creating a custom column based on the previous step.

The `(C) =>` syntax is a bit more tricky, but basically, it's used to allow me to compare the `FullDate` in the table we're operating on (`#"[Previous Step Name Here]"`) with the `FullDate` in the current step. Check out [this blog post](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2018/01/09/each-keyword-power-query/) for much more info related to this.

Comment: Fantastic Alexis !! It worked perfectly. May I ask you explain the code, I don't quite understand the "[Previous Step Name Here]" and the (C) => C[Fulldate] ... and how all of that works in the issue.

Comment: Is the way to consider fullDate column?
Starting with new year in row of  "fullDate" column, restart calculation of rolling average.... 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use an average function on the dates up to the current one.

As a calculated column, it would look something like this:

```
AvgPresented = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(
        Table1[CallsPresent]),
        ALL(Table1),
        Table1[FullDate] <= EARLIER(Table1[FullDate]
    )
)
```

or this:

```
AvgPresented:
AVERAGEX(
    FILTER(
        Table1,
        Table1[FullDate] <= EARLIER(Table1[FullDate])
    ),
    Table1[CallsPresent]
)
```

---

Note: The `EARLIER` function is referring to the earlier row context (i.e. the values in the current row) and has nothing to do with times or dates.

Comment: Is this DAX? In the Power Query Editor, I am getting "Expression.Error: The name 'AVERAGEX' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.". Like I said, I am a real newbie to Power BI.

Comment: Yes, I may have misread the question. DAX is indeed different than the query editor M language.